# How To Get Icons For Pictures Files in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, filesystems, icons

I Tried To Get Icons Of files system and display it in my list Box 
But i got an empty icon For Picture Files

This Is My Code:

```
Public Sub ExtractAssociatedIconEx()
    ' Initialize the ListView, ImageList and Form.
    listView1 = New ListView()
    imageList1 = New ImageList()
    listView1.Location = New Point(37, 12)
    listView1.Size = New Size(161, 242)
    listView1.SmallImageList = imageList1
    listView1.View = View.SmallIcon
    Me.ClientSize = New System.Drawing.Size(292, 266)
    Me.Controls.Add(Me.listView1)
    Me.Text = "Form1"

    ' Get the c:\ directory. 
    Dim dir As New System.IO.DirectoryInfo(TextBox1.Text)

    Dim item As ListViewItem
    listView1.BeginUpdate()
    Dim file As System.IO.FileInfo
    For Each file In dir.GetFiles()

        ' Set a default icon for the file. 
        Dim iconForFile As Icon = SystemIcons.WinLogo

        item = New ListViewItem(file.Name, 1)

        ' Check to see if the image collection contains an image 
        ' for this extension, using the extension as a key. 
        If Not (imageList1.Images.ContainsKey(file.Extension)) Then

            ' If not, add the image to the image list.
            iconForFile = System.Drawing.Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(file.FullName)
            imageList1.Images.Add(file.Extension, iconForFile)
        End If
        item.ImageKey = file.Extension
        listView1.Items.Add(item)

    Next file
    listView1.EndUpdate()
End Sub
```

How I Can Get Icons For picture Files ?

Thanks

Comment: What is the problem. For me it works perfectly fine

Comment: This Code return All Files Icon With no problem , But dose't return Picture Icon only an empty Icon